# Asp.net loading screen/hide form

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, forms, loading

I have an asp.net form with textboxes, ddls, buttons, etc.
One of the posts takes a while to complete.

What is the quickest way to darken the page, make the user unable to select any of the form's controls and display a rotating loading bar, until the form is posted?

Is there something like that built into jquery?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I add an hidden modal popup and then when you click the button i open it. Since the popup has autoOpen=false it will be closed after postback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=dialog.ClientID %>").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,height: 100,width: 200,modal: true,closeOnEscape: false,resizable: false,
            open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
            beforeClose: function (event, ui) { return false; }
        });
        $("#buttonId").click(function () {
                $("#<%=dialog.ClientID %>").dialog("open");
        });
    })
</script>
    <div runat="server" id="dialog" title="Loading ">
    <p>Loading...</p>
    </div>
```

A possible improvement is embed this into a user control or in the master page and use a class selector instead of the button name. I.e. $('.slowButton').

This means that you can choose which buttons apply the effect to symply adding the slowButton css class.

Comment: I get this `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog' ` jquery is imported at the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $loader = $('<img src="loader.gif">').appendTo(document.body);
```

then in success method

```
success: function (data) {
           $loader.remove();
        }
```

it will hide the screen till success method is not called

or you can use below plugin

http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: Ok so if I want the loadbar to appear just after a button is clicked, and to dissappear right after the post is complete. How to call it?

Comment: @sd_dracula: in button click event append loader before calling the post method and then in post success method remove the loader.